# win32 API string types - conversion between LPSTR and char *

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writing a function that creates a file using the win32 API

```
void createFile(HWND hwnd, LPTSTR pszFile, PBITMAPINFO pbi, HBITMAP hBMP, HDC hDC)
```

I've also written a function that dynamically generates a file name based on the current time.

```
char * getFilename() {
   char filename[200] = "";
   char buf[40];
   SYSTEMTIME st;
   GetSystemTime(&st);
   itoa(st.wHour, buf,10)
   strcat(filename,buf);
   .....
   return filename;
}
```

I call the above function like:

```
createFile(hwnd, getFilename, pbi, hBMP, hDC);
```

Passing through the debugger, the filename is correct until after the first statement  in createFile() is executed and the string suddenly becomes "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ"

It's clear I have some sort of type error, but I am unsure how to fix it. I am new to the win32 API and have a lot of trouble understanding the various types used, so I would appreciate any help fixing this issue

Comment: BTW, the "ÌÌÌ..." comes from compiler trying to be helpful.  In debug builds, MSVC fills stack buffers like this when they go out of scope, in order to help you find bugs like this.  If it didn't do that, there's a chance that the pointer will still point to memory that has the string you expected, and it would appear to work even though it was actually a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to `filename`, which has been allocated on the stack inside `getFilename` and so is freed when the function returns.

EDIT: To avoid confusion - the memory is allocated on the stack, not on the heap (via `malloc` or `new`). So "it is freed" does not refer to calling `free` (or `delete`). Rather to the fact that it is no longer reserved. Not available for use anymore. Deallocated. Bereft of bytes. This is a non-buffer.

For a solution, consider allocating the memory outside of `getFileName`. This can be done on the stack by the caller, who passes the buffer as a parameter. Naturally, using a string class would be an option.

Comment: It's not `freed`, since it was never allocated - it's a stack-based array, and so the behaviour in accessing this memory after the function returns is undefined (usually/probably bad).  This could be a good answer if you clarified this, and added suggestion to allocate the memory from the heap instead.

Comment: "The lifetime of the object has ended."

Comment: The ghost of the object may linger.

Comment: "Naturally, using a string class would be an option" *if* the implementation language had string classes.  But the question is tagged as C, not C++.